# Is there a way to automatically specify a custom format for links in slack?

Tags: slack, slack-commands

I regularly post links from Github, Jira and others into Slack. Is there a simple way to set up a regex to process links?

Example 1: The text for the link https://github.com/my_org/main_project/pull/4208 would automatically be `PR-4208`.

Example 2: The text for the link https://my-org.atlassian.net/browse/ENG-123 would automatically be `ENG-123`.